# Dynamic list in html (bootstrap list)

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of bootstrap component class="list-group"
I have a folder of videos/category,
I want to when I click on a category, the list updates without loading a page (by changing the path).
Have this code :

```
    <div class="list-group">
    <?php
        $directory = "./videos/";

        $videos = glob($directory . "*.*");


        foreach($videos as $video)
        {
            $pathp = pathinfo($video);
            echo '<a href="' .  $video . '"class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">' . $pathp['basename']. ' - <b>(' . round(filesize($video) / pow(1024,2 ), 2) .') Mo</b>' .'</a>';
        }
    ?>                  
    </div>
```

I'm not asking for a complete code, just idea I have to read.
I'm not using jQuery, just Bootstrap and pure JavaScript!
Thank you.

Comment: You're probably looking for ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax in combination with jquery to achieve this. Jquery will make everything easier for the ajax call ;)